# Цвет бэкграунда

Tags: java, android, color

Нужно поменять цвет всего RecyclerView элемента. У меня получилось только так, как на скриншоте, а нужно, чтобы то, что окрашено в белый, было того же цвета (коричневого).

Окрашивал через android:background.
colorBackground и windowBackground не окрашивают совсем.

Подскажите, как решить проблему.

Скриншот:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут всё просто.

Вам надо в **onBindViewHolder()** методе адаптера получить ссылку на **ViewGroup** элемента списка. И присвоить ему цвет фона. Ссылку можно получить методом **getParent()** класса **View**.

Т.е., положим, у вас в холдере всего один дочерний элемент, коий вы к классе холдера назвали **text**. Тогда весь элемент можно так получить:

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) yoursHolder.text.getParent();
vg.setBackgroundColor(act.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
```